# Get SharePoint list data from outside SharePoint Online using c#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I'm having a SharePoint online list and need to fetch data from that list from outside of SharePoint.
I need to use Access token approach, for that i have created a app in azure AD in same tenant and trying to get list but its giving Unauthorized error.

I have tried to use SharePoint REST api and passing token in headers. i have refereed the below URL:
https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/
But its giving me error as "{"error_description":"Invalid JWT token. The token is expired."}" in Postman itself.
I have added api permissions in App registrations and manifest also still no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, firstly create a access token and then make a http request by passing token.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("SiteURL"))
                {                   
                    context.ExecutingWebRequest += Context_ExecutingWebRequest;
}

public void Context_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + GetAccessToken();
        }
 public string GetAccessToken()
        {
            try
            {
                #region Get Access token for Azure AD access              
                var client = new RestClient("https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/" + TenantID + "/tokens/OAuth/2");
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);                
                request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
                request.AddParameter("client_id", "ClientID@TenantID");
                request.AddParameter("client_secret", "ClientSecret");
                request.AddParameter("resource", "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/SharePointSite@TenantID");
                IRestResponse restClientResponse = client.Execute(request);
                var DeserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BearerToken>(restClientResponse.Content.ToString());
                string accessToken = DeserializeObject.AccessToken;
                #endregion           

                return accessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the steps in the link you provided. It works fine for me.

This error is caused by the expiration of the client secret of the app you registered at https://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx.

You could register a new app or [replace an expiring client secret in a SharePoint Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/replace-an-expiring-client-secret-in-a-sharepoint-add-in).

Comment: i'm getting "{"error_description":"Invalid JWT token. Could not resolve issuer token."}" error while using same steps on SharePoint online.

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal When did you create the app at https://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx?

Comment: i got the bearer token and can get web using rest api successfully, now i want to get list SPlist object so that i can use it in my existing code

Answer (score 0):

The app you registered in azure and SharePoint add-in are different, and the tokens are different also.

You could use add-in authentication to access SharePoint.

[Demo thread here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d33f5818-f112-42fb-becf-3cf14ac5f940/app-only-token-issue-unauthorized-access?forum=appsforsharepoint)

If you do want to use azure app to access SharePoint, you could check [this thread](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/Connecting-to-SharePoint-Online-from-console-application-with-Azure-AD-and-PnP-Core-Component).